# I found SwfDotNet to help me create swf flash files with C#, but

Tags: c#, flash

I found SwfDotNet to help me create swf flash files with C#, but I need some documentation or some examples on how to use this better.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/swfdotnet/

I'd like to be able to take multiple images and create a slide show, and have some transitions between them. Nothing fancy, but I can find the details on how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know how I missed it, but I checked again and there is some very nice documentation in a separate CHM help file download.

http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=154817&package_id=215074&release_id=471242